# Unity3D : Blur the background of a UI canvas

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, uiblureffect

I'm trying to create a blur effect on the background of a UI window for my game in Unity3D.

One of the best examples I can think of right now is Heroes Of The Storm, notice how the background of the Level Up panel blurs what's behind it :

[image: Heroes Of The Storm Blur Effect]

Is there any way to reproduce the same effect with the recently-added Canvas in Unity3D?
I know there is a way to do so by using a camera, but I'm not really familiar with the whole thing, especially when it comes to making it work with the new UI system.

Thanks.

Comment: blurring the background can be cpu intensive. you can sometimes do a trick by having a static blurred version of the background which you then put over the top

Comment: in fact i think thats what has been done in your example. you can see the number 2 isnt blurred

Comment: @Ewan see [this](http://i.imgur.com/V20dZoZ.jpg) and [this](http://i.imgur.com/mSIpfR4.jpg). It's not static blur. Also animations are blurred when they are behind a dialogue when in menus, unlike the screenshots that are in game.

Comment: in which case a second camera with a blurring shader

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a shader script that works nicely for me.

Source: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-dynamic-blurred-background-on-ui.345083/#post-2853442

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "Unlit/FrostedGlass"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Radius("Radius", Range(1, 255)) = 1
    }

    Category
    {
        Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

        SubShader
        {
            GrabPass
            {
                Tags{ "LightMode" = "Always" }
            }

            Pass
            {
                Tags{ "LightMode" = "Always" }

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert(appdata_t v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    float scale = -1.0;
                    #else
                    float scale = 1.0;
                    #endif
                    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y*scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _GrabTexture;
                float4 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;
                float _Radius;

                half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
                {
                    half4 sum = half4(0,0,0,0);

                    #define GRABXYPIXEL(kernelx, kernely) tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(float4(i.uvgrab.x + _GrabTexture_TexelSize.x * kernelx, i.uvgrab.y + _GrabTexture_TexelSize.y * kernely, i.uvgrab.z, i.uvgrab.w)))

                    sum += GRABXYPIXEL(0.0, 0.0);
                    int measurments = 1;

                    for (float range = 0.1f; range <= _Radius; range += 0.1f)
                    {
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(range, range);
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(range, -range);
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(-range, range);
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(-range, -range);
                        measurments += 4;
                    }

                    return sum / measurments;
                }
                ENDCG
            }
            GrabPass
            {
                Tags{ "LightMode" = "Always" }
            }

            Pass
            {
                Tags{ "LightMode" = "Always" }

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert(appdata_t v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    float scale = -1.0;
                    #else
                    float scale = 1.0;
                    #endif
                    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y*scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _GrabTexture;
                float4 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;
                float _Radius;

                half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
                {

                    half4 sum = half4(0,0,0,0);
                    float radius = 1.41421356237 * _Radius;

                    #define GRABXYPIXEL(kernelx, kernely) tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(float4(i.uvgrab.x + _GrabTexture_TexelSize.x * kernelx, i.uvgrab.y + _GrabTexture_TexelSize.y * kernely, i.uvgrab.z, i.uvgrab.w)))

                    sum += GRABXYPIXEL(0.0, 0.0);
                    int measurments = 1;

                    for (float range = 1.41421356237f; range <= radius * 1.41; range += 1.41421356237f)
                    {
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(range, 0);
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(-range, 0);
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(0, range);
                        sum += GRABXYPIXEL(0, -range);
                        measurments += 4;
                    }

                    return sum / measurments;
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any easy reason for why this shader loopbacks on itself?  ie the background blur feeds back to itself frame by frame resulting in more blurring every frame (which itself is a neat effect but not really what i was looking for)

Comment: Tried to use on iPhone 8+, full screen image blur, value 15. And it made the phone hot very quickly. The shader below has no such a problem.

Comment: As I understand, the difference between this shader (A) and below (B) is signinficant. A has O(r^2) complexity and is closer to true blur (big r can lead to perfomance problems). B has O(r) complexity, and it's simpler. We adjusted B-shader to our requirements and it's light and works fine. Keep in mind, that your requirements can be different.

Comment: this is not working for me. Unity version 2021.3.3f1

Comment: I like the look of the shader but it completly crashed my laptop after I mindlessly turned up the radius value :)

Answer (score 14):

I modified this one a little. Added **tint color** and **UI compatibility**. Although while using on UI is possible, makes UI before it invisible.

```
    // Based on cician's shader from https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-optimized-blur-shader.185327/#post-1267642

Shader "Custom/MaskedUIBlur" {
    Properties {
        _Size ("Blur", Range(0, 30)) = 1
        [HideInInspector] _MainTex ("Masking Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _AdditiveColor ("Additive Tint color", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        _MultiplyColor ("Multiply Tint color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    Category {

        // We must be transparent, so other objects are drawn before this one.
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Opaque" }


        SubShader
        {
            // Horizontal blur
            GrabPass
            {
                "_HBlur"
            }
            /*
            ZTest Off
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            */

            Cull Off
            Lighting Off
            ZWrite Off
            ZTest [unity_GUIZTestMode]
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            Pass
            {          
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
                    float2 uvmain : TEXCOORD1;
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;

                v2f vert (appdata_t v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    float scale = -1.0;
                    #else
                    float scale = 1.0;
                    #endif

                    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y * scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;

                    o.uvmain = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _HBlur;
                float4 _HBlur_TexelSize;
                float _Size;
                float4 _AdditiveColor;
                float4 _MultiplyColor;

                half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR
                {   
                    half4 sum = half4(0,0,0,0);

                    #define GRABPIXEL(weight,kernelx) tex2Dproj( _HBlur, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(float4(i.uvgrab.x + _HBlur_TexelSize.x * kernelx * _Size, i.uvgrab.y, i.uvgrab.z, i.uvgrab.w))) * weight

                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, -4.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, -3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, -2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, -1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.18,  0.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, +1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, +2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, +3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, +4.0);


                    half4 result = half4(sum.r * _MultiplyColor.r + _AdditiveColor.r, 
                                        sum.g * _MultiplyColor.g + _AdditiveColor.g, 
                                        sum.b * _MultiplyColor.b + _AdditiveColor.b, 
                                        tex2D(_MainTex, i.uvmain).a);
                    return result;
                }
                ENDCG
            }

            // Vertical blur
            GrabPass
            {
                "_VBlur"
            }

            Pass
            {          
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
                    float2 uvmain : TEXCOORD1;
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;

                v2f vert (appdata_t v) {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    float scale = -1.0;
                    #else
                    float scale = 1.0;
                    #endif

                    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y * scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;

                    o.uvmain = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);

                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _VBlur;
                float4 _VBlur_TexelSize;
                float _Size;
                float4 _AdditiveColor;
                float4 _MultiplyColor;

                half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR
                {
                    half4 sum = half4(0,0,0,0);

                    #define GRABPIXEL(weight,kernely) tex2Dproj( _VBlur, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(float4(i.uvgrab.x, i.uvgrab.y + _VBlur_TexelSize.y * kernely * _Size, i.uvgrab.z, i.uvgrab.w))) * weight

                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, -4.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, -3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, -2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, -1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.18,  0.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, +1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, +2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, +3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, +4.0);

                    half4 result = half4(sum.r * _MultiplyColor.r + _AdditiveColor.r, 
                                        sum.g * _MultiplyColor.g + _AdditiveColor.g, 
                                        sum.b * _MultiplyColor.b + _AdditiveColor.b, 
                                        tex2D(_MainTex, i.uvmain).a);
                    return result;
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me (however, the selected answer version did not). Thanks!

Comment: works great, thanks! I needed the blurred background to be greyscale instead of color, so I modified the shader to add a toggle for that https://gist.github.com/jhocking/9de4197daf84698a60e51c67695d2be3

Comment: How can we use this with URP?

Comment: with unity 2020.3 it results with "Material doesn't have _Stencil property"