# Unity - glossy blur material?

Tags: unity-game-engine, material-design, virtual-reality

Ok Im trying to do a standard blur material like this (the darkened beat saber menu)

[image]

Or [image]

But on a 3D object, so not a camera effect or canvas material. I found some assets that provide a low quality blur but I need it glossy, and a nice Gaussian blur. The one I have has weird streaks:

[image]

// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

```
Shader "Custom/WaterBlur" {
    Properties {
    _blurSizeXY("BlurSizeXY", Range(0,10)) = 0
}
    SubShader {

        // Draw ourselves after all opaque geometry
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" }

        // Grab the screen behind the object into _GrabTexture
        GrabPass { }

        // Render the object with the texture generated above
        Pass {


CGPROGRAM
#pragma debug
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag 
#ifndef SHADER_API_D3D11

    #pragma target 3.0

#else

    #pragma target 4.0

#endif

            sampler2D _GrabTexture : register(s0);
            float _blurSizeXY;

struct data {

    float4 vertex : POSITION;

    float3 normal : NORMAL;

};



struct v2f {

    float4 position : POSITION;

    float4 screenPos : TEXCOORD0;

};



v2f vert(data i){

    v2f o;

    o.position = UnityObjectToClipPos(i.vertex);

    o.screenPos = o.position;

    return o;

}



half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR

{

    float2 screenPos = i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.w;
    float depth= _blurSizeXY*0.0005;

    screenPos.x = (screenPos.x + 1) * 0.5;

    screenPos.y = 1-(screenPos.y + 1) * 0.5;

    half4 sum = half4(0.0h,0.0h,0.0h,0.0h);   
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-5.0 * depth, screenPos.y+5.0 * depth)) * 0.025;    
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+5.0 * depth, screenPos.y-5.0 * depth)) * 0.025;

    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-4.0 * depth, screenPos.y+4.0 * depth)) * 0.05;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+4.0 * depth, screenPos.y-4.0 * depth)) * 0.05;


    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-3.0 * depth, screenPos.y+3.0 * depth)) * 0.09;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+3.0 * depth, screenPos.y-3.0 * depth)) * 0.09;

    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-2.0 * depth, screenPos.y+2.0 * depth)) * 0.12;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+2.0 * depth, screenPos.y-2.0 * depth)) * 0.12;

    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x-1.0 * depth, screenPos.y+1.0 * depth)) *  0.15;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, float2(screenPos.x+1.0 * depth, screenPos.y-1.0 * depth)) *  0.15;



    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-5.0 * depth) * 0.025;    
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-4.0 * depth) * 0.05;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-3.0 * depth) * 0.09;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-2.0 * depth) * 0.12;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos-1.0 * depth) * 0.15;    
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos) * 0.16; 
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+5.0 * depth) * 0.15;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+4.0 * depth) * 0.12;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+3.0 * depth) * 0.09;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+2.0 * depth) * 0.05;
    sum += tex2D( _GrabTexture, screenPos+1.0 * depth) * 0.025;

    return sum/2;

}
ENDCG
        }
    }

Fallback Off
}
```

How can I accomplish a glossy, or even just a highqaulity gaussian blur material for a mesh?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43575634/1092820) was to a question about a UI effect, but should work for any material as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Ruzihm fantastic thanks! the 2nd answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030321/unity3d-blur-the-background-of-a-ui-canvas worked, but now on the second part of what I need, how could I make this material glossy? Is it possible or do I need to overlay another mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include a gloss onto your surface, here is one way to do it, based on the shader in the [Glossy Textures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Glossy_Textures) article in the Unity Community wiki copied below:

> ```
> Shader "Cg per-pixel lighting with texture" {
>    Properties {
>       _MainTex ("RGBA Texture For Material Color", 2D) = "white" {} 
>       _Color ("Diffuse Material Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
>       _SpecColor ("Specular Material Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
>       _Shininess ("Shininess", Float) = 10
>    }
>    SubShader {
>       Pass {    
>          Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" } 
>             // pass for ambient light and first light source
>
>          CGPROGRAM
>
>          #pragma vertex vert  
>          #pragma fragment frag 
>
>          #include "UnityCG.cginc"
>          uniform float4 _LightColor0; 
>             // color of light source (from "Lighting.cginc")
>
>          // User-specified properties
>          uniform sampler2D _MainTex;    
>          uniform float4 _Color; 
>          uniform float4 _SpecColor; 
>          uniform float _Shininess;
>
>          struct vertexInput {
>             float4 vertex : POSITION;
>             float3 normal : NORMAL;
>             float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
>         };
>          struct vertexOutput {
>             float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
>             float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD0;
>             float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD1;
>             float4 tex : TEXCOORD2;
>         };
>
>          vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) 
>          {
>             vertexOutput output;
>
>             float4x4 modelMatrix = unity_ObjectToWorld;
>             float4x4 modelMatrixInverse = unity_WorldToObject;
>
>             output.posWorld = mul(modelMatrix, input.vertex);
>             output.normalDir = normalize(
>                mul(float4(input.normal, 0.0), modelMatrixInverse).xyz);
>             output.tex = input.texcoord;
>             output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, input.vertex);
>             return output;
>          }
>
>          float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
>          {
>             float3 normalDirection = normalize(input.normalDir);
>
>             float3 viewDirection = normalize(
>                _WorldSpaceCameraPos - input.posWorld.xyz);
>             float3 lightDirection;
>             float attenuation;
>
>             float4 textureColor = tex2D(_MainTex, input.tex.xy);
>
>             if (0.0 == _WorldSpaceLightPos0.w) // directional light?
>             {
>                attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation
>                lightDirection = 
>                   normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
>             } 
>             else // point or spot light
>             {
>                float3 vertexToLightSource = 
>                   _WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - input.posWorld.xyz;
>                float distance = length(vertexToLightSource);
>                attenuation = 1.0 / distance; // linear attenuation 
>                lightDirection = normalize(vertexToLightSource);
>             }
>
>             float3 ambientLighting = textureColor.rgb  
>                * UNITY_LIGHTMODEL_AMBIENT.rgb * _Color.rgb;
>
>             float3 diffuseReflection = textureColor.rgb  
>                * attenuation * _LightColor0.rgb * _Color.rgb
>                * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));
>
>             float3 specularReflection;
>             if (dot(normalDirection, lightDirection) < 0.0) 
>                // light source on the wrong side?
>             {
>                specularReflection = float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
>                   // no specular reflection
>             }
>             else // light source on the right side
>             {
>                specularReflection = attenuation * _LightColor0.rgb 
>                   * _SpecColor.rgb * (1.0 - textureColor.a) 
>                      // for usual gloss maps: "... * textureColor.a" 
>                   * pow(max(0.0, dot(
>                   reflect(-lightDirection, normalDirection), 
>                   viewDirection)), _Shininess);
>             }
>
>             return float4(ambientLighting + diffuseReflection 
>                + specularReflection, 1.0);
>          }
>
>          ENDCG
>       }
>
>       Pass {    
>          Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardAdd" } 
>             // pass for additional light sources
>          Blend One One // additive blending 
>
>           CGPROGRAM
>
>          #pragma vertex vert  
>          #pragma fragment frag 
>
>          #include "UnityCG.cginc"
>          uniform float4 _LightColor0; 
>             // color of light source (from "Lighting.cginc")
>
>          // User-specified properties
>          uniform sampler2D _MainTex;    
>          uniform float4 _Color; 
>          uniform float4 _SpecColor; 
>          uniform float _Shininess;
>
>         struct vertexInput {
>             float4 vertex : POSITION;
>             float3 normal : NORMAL;
>             float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
>         };
>          struct vertexOutput {
>             float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
>             float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD0;
>             float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD1;
>             float4 tex : TEXCOORD2;
>         };
>
>          vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) 
>          {
>             vertexOutput output;
>
>             float4x4 modelMatrix = unity_ObjectToWorld;
>             float4x4 modelMatrixInverse = unity_WorldToObject;
>
>             output.posWorld = mul(modelMatrix, input.vertex);
>             output.normalDir = normalize(
>                mul(float4(input.normal, 0.0), modelMatrixInverse).xyz);
>             output.tex = input.texcoord;
>             output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, input.vertex);
>             return output;
>          }
>
>          float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
>          {
>             float3 normalDirection = normalize(input.normalDir);
>
>             float3 viewDirection = normalize(
>                _WorldSpaceCameraPos - input.posWorld.xyz);
>             float3 lightDirection;
>             float attenuation;
>
>             float4 textureColor = tex2D(_MainTex, input.tex.xy);
>
>             if (0.0 == _WorldSpaceLightPos0.w) // directional light?
>             {
>                attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation
>                lightDirection = 
>                   normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
>             } 
>             else // point or spot light
>             {
>                float3 vertexToLightSource = 
>                   _WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - input.posWorld.xyz;
>                float distance = length(vertexToLightSource);
>                attenuation = 1.0 / distance; // linear attenuation 
>                lightDirection = normalize(vertexToLightSource);
>             }
>
>             float3 diffuseReflection = textureColor.rgb  
>                * attenuation * _LightColor0.rgb * _Color.rgb
>                * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));
>
>             float3 specularReflection;
>             if (dot(normalDirection, lightDirection) < 0.0) 
>                // light source on the wrong side?
>             {
>                specularReflection = float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
>                   // no specular reflection
>             }
>             else // light source on the right side
>             {
>                specularReflection = attenuation * _LightColor0.rgb 
>                   * _SpecColor.rgb * (1.0 - textureColor.a) 
>                      // for usual gloss maps: "... * textureColor.a" 
>                   * pow(max(0.0, dot(
>                   reflect(-lightDirection, normalDirection), 
>                   viewDirection)), _Shininess);
>             }
>
>             return float4(diffuseReflection 
>                + specularReflection, 1.0);
>                // no ambient lighting in this pass
>          }
>
>          ENDCG
>       }
>    }
>    Fallback "Specular"
> }
> ```

The final `Pass` of your blur shader will need to be merged into the first and second `Pass`es in the above shader.

#### Shader Properties

Add these properties in the blur shader if they don't already exist (you may need to rename things if they do):

```
  _MainTex ("RGBA Texture For Material Color", 2D) = "white" {} 
  _Color ("Diffuse Material Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
  _SpecColor ("Specular Material Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
  _Shininess ("Shininess", Float) = 10
```

#### The first gloss pass

Set the tag to match the glossy shader: `"LightMode" = "ForwardBase"`

Add these variables to the pass if they don't already exist (you may need to rename things if they do):

```
 uniform sampler2D _MainTex; 
 uniform float4 _Color; 
 uniform float4 _SpecColor; 
 uniform float _Shininess;
```

Include `float3 normal : NORMAL;` in your vertex input structure.

Include `float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD0;` and `float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD1;` in your vertex output structure.

In the `vert` function, set `output.posWorld` and `output.normalDir` the same way the glossy shader `vert` does.

Then, in the `frag` function, take what your blur shader is already returning, and instead of returning it, use it as the `textureColor` variable in the 1st `frag` function in the glossy shader, and then do the rest of the 1st glossy `frag`.

You will probably have to rename other things in the code to make it work with the pass you already have. I don't know what your blur shader looks like, so it's impossible for me to list every step in merging the two passes together.

#### The second gloss pass

Repeat the same process as the first gloss `Pass`, but using the code from the 2nd gloss `Pass` (especially important is the different tag `"LightMode" = "ForwardAdd"`)